# "File Not found" while trying to execute java file on MacBook Pro

Tags: java, macos

Am trying to execute a java method, am having my java first.java which I compiled using `javac first.java`, After which a class file got created in the same path but when I tried executing the class file using command `javac first.class` it throws error saying **file not found**.  Any idea by the way I have both JDK and JRE in the path variable.  Am using java 1.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `java first` to execute, `javac` is for compile.

Comment: Shouldn't it be in the order which I mentioned first. compile and then execute the compiled file java is new to me so ignore if my question sounds stupids

Comment: Yes, you have compiled it with `javac first.java`, then you need `java first` to execute.

Comment: @AdarshHDDev See the doc, you do not need `.class` when execute it  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/compile-136656.html